# Convert String or int To Enum in JPA

Tags: jpa

I don't know how I can persist an entity(with enum) to the database.
When I fill my form like this;

`form.setTypZamowienia(SlownikZamowienie.SENIOR)`

then 666 is stored in the database. But when I try like this;

`form.setTypZamowienia(SlownikZamowienie.valueOf(request.getParameter("typKlienta").trim()));`

0 is stored in the database.

How do I make this work?
For any help I will be very grateful.

My enum :

```
public enum SlownikZamowienie 
{
    JUNIOR(42), 
    SENIOR(666), 
    PRINCIPAL(31416);    
    private final int wartosc;
    SlownikZamowienie(int wartosc) {
        this.wartosc = wartosc;
    }
}
```

My Entity:

```
package test.jpa.domain;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import test.enums.SlownikZamowienie;

@Entity
@Table(name="Piess")
public class Pies implements Serializable {
    private static final Long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    int id;
    @Column(name = "imie")
    String imie;
    @Enumerated
    @Column(name = "rasa")
    SlownikZamowienie typzamowienia;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getImie() {
        return imie;
    }

    public void setImie(String imie) {
        this.imie = imie;
    }

    public SlownikZamowienie getTypzamowienia() {
        return typzamowienia;
    }

    public void setTypzamowienia(SlownikZamowienie typzamowienia) {
        this.typzamowienia = typzamowienia;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no way 666 is saved to the database. Unless you use Enumerated(STRING), the ordinal is saved, i.e. 0 for JUNIOR, 1 for SENIOR, 2 for PRINCIPAL

Answer (score 0):

As of JPA 2.1 you can use an attribute converter (known as a UserType in the Hibernate world). See these two articles for details on how to implement such a solution:

1. [www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-type-converter-better-way-to/](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-type-converter-better-way-to/)
2. [www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/)